# Undefined offset Error when searching Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am searching an array for a known value `wid` to get the key which will then help me get the `cid` value.

```
$proximity = array(
    '0' => array ('wid' => 4, 'cid' => 100),
    '1' => array ('wid' => 1, 'cid' => 50),
    '3' => array ('wid' => 2, 'cid' => 50)
);

$key = array_search(2, array_column($proximity, 'wid'));
    print_r($key);
    print_r($proximity[$key]['cid']);
```

When I search for `wid` `4` and `1` everything works great.

However when I search for `wid: 2` I get `Undefined offset: 2`.

---

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: What does `print_r($key);` show?

Comment: @JohnConde the `'0' => array` row key.

Comment: `$key` has a value of `2` and there is no element in your array with a key of 2 so this error makes sense

Comment: That is because you don't have any value at '2' position in $proximity array. Try changing your last element in $proximity array index to i.e. '3' to '2'

Comment: @JohnConde But I am not searching by key, with array_column I am searching the wid and getting the key. A wid with value of 2 does exist!

Comment: @AlamDarji The proximity array will be automatically generated. I made it like this for testing purposes. So I can have gaps between the rows. And again I am using array_column to search by wid with value 2. Which does exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array_column returns values of field as usual indexed array, even if source array is associative. So the returned key is correct only when source array has no omitted indexes, and your search, in fact, gets "position" in array.

For example, for such an array

```
$proximity = array(
    'a' => array ('wid' => 4, 'cid' => 100),
    'b' => array ('wid' => 1, 'cid' => 50),
    'c' => array ('wid' => 2, 'cid' => 50)
);
```

array_column will return

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

If you really want to search through array_column, to work around this problem and get item by that "position", use

```
print_r(array_slice($proximity, $key, 1)['cid']);
```

or

```
print_r(array_values($proximity)[$key]['cid']);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because when you are doing array_search() it is only searching the first level of the array, you can search like the following:

```
<?php

echo 'hello world';

$proximity = array(
    '0' => array ('wid' => 4, 'cid' => 100),
    '1' => array ('wid' => 1, 'cid' => 50),
    '3' => array ('wid' => 2, 'cid' => 50)
);

foreach($proximity as $subarray){
    $key = array_search(2, array_column($subarray, 'wid'));
    echo print_r($key) . '<br />';
    echo print_r($proximity[$key]['cid']) . '<br />';
}

?>
```

This searches each sub array that is in the main array, meaning it doesn't matter how many elements are in $proximity, it will search all of them.

Comment: I am trying not to have loops.

Answer (score 0):

`array_column()` is trashing your original keys.  I don't think there is any shame in using a loop with a break.  This is clean and fast and the gaps in the keys are no bother; in fact your original keys are preserved if you need them.

Code:  (demo: https://3v4l.org/8XWcf )

```
$proximity = array(
    '0' => array ('wid' => 4, 'cid' => 100),
    '1' => array ('wid' => 1, 'cid' => 50),
    '3' => array ('wid' => 2, 'cid' => 50)
);

$wid=2;
foreach($proximity as $i=>$a){
    if($a['wid']==$wid){
        echo "i=$i and cid={$a['cid']}";
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
i=3 and cid=50
```

---

If you don't want control structures as iterators, this seems like a sensible alternative:

```
$wid=2;
$proximity=array_column($proximity,NULL,'wid');
if(isset($proximity[$wid])){
    echo "cid={$proximity[$wid]['cid']}";
}else{
    echo 'wid not found';
}
```

This assumes `wid` values are unique and uses the values as keys for the subarrays.  Demo : https://3v4l.org/Ph1tH

Comment: @borsn sorry I'm slow on my phone.  I just read your comment on the other answer saying that you don't want to use loops.  I've added another way which uses `array_column()` differently versus your snippet.